# Is holding the wall or bouncing up off the bottom legal in water polo?

Tags: rules, water-polo

Is it okay to hold the edge of the pool or touch the bottom of the pool during a game of water polo?

The pool I will play in is 2 metres deep and I'm 1.89 metres tall so that's why I thought of the bottom.

I read that it's illegal to push off the wall, which is fine because that gives you an advantage. Is it okay to hold on to it if you're just tired?

This isn't really a very high level of competition either, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [FINA](https://www.fina.org/) [WATER POLO RULES](https://www.fina.org/content/water-polo-rules):

> [WP 20 ORDINARY FOULS](https://www.fina.org/content/wp-20-ordinary-fouls)
>
> - WP 20.1 It shall be an ordinary foul to commit any of the following offences (WP 20.2 to WP 20.17), which shall be punished by awarding of a free throw to the opposing team.
> - WP 20.4 To hold or push off from the goal posts or their fixtures, to hold or push off from the sides or ends of the pool during actual play or at the start of a period.
> - WP 20.5 To take any active part in the game when standing on the floor of the pool, to walk when play is in progress or to jump from the floor of the pool to play the ball or tackle an opponent. This Rule shall not apply to the goalkeeper while within the goalkeeper’s 5 metre area.
>
> [WP 21 EXCLUSION FOULS](https://www.fina.org/content/wp-21-exclusion-fouls)
>
> - WP 21.1 It shall be an exclusion foul to commit any of the following offences (WP 21.4 to WP 21.18) which shall be punished (except as otherwise provided by the Rules) by the award of a free throw to the opposing team and the exclusion of the player who committed the foul.
> - WP 21.4 For a player to leave the water or sit or stand on the steps or side of the pool during play, except in the case of accident, injury, illness or with the permission of a referee.
>
> Read [WP 24 PERSONAL FOULS](https://www.fina.org/content/wp-24-personal-fouls)
>
> [WP 25 ACCIDENT, INJURY AND ILLNESS](https://www.fina.org/content/wp-25-accident-injury-and-illness)
>
> - WP 25.1 A player shall only be allowed to leave the water, or sit or stand on the steps or side of the pool during play in the case of accident, injury, illness or with the permission of a referee. A player who has left the water legitimately may re-enter from the re-entry area nearest his own goal line at an appropriate stoppage, with the permission of a referee.

---

> Is it ok to hold the edge of the pool during a game of Water polo?

No, it is not ok to hold the edge of the pool except in the case of accident, injury, illness or with the permission of a referee. (see WP 21.4)

> Is it ok to touch the bottom of the pool during a game of Water polo?

No, it is not ok to take any active part in the game when standing on the floor of the pool, to walk when play is in progress or to jump from the floor of the pool to play the ball or tackle an opponent. (see WP 20.5)